# How to prevent that a channel exception make a WCF service stop working?

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, timeout, channel

I created a WCF singleton service with netNamedPipeBinding. When a channel exception occurs, it leaves a channel in a faulty state, and all subsequent operations throws exceptions. How can I prevent this? I want that a TimeoutException, or any of the other common exceptions, to make only one operation fail, and not to make the service unresponsive.

Comment: Are you sure it's the service channel that becomes unresponsive on error? I use singleton services all the time on a very large site, and I've never had the problem you describe.

Comment: I got logs that says that the channel is unusable because it is in a faulty state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way. You can instantiate the client proxy for each request instead of using a single instance for more than one request. This way if the channel enters a faulty state, it is discarded anyway.

This is a bit tricky because you shouldn't dispose a channel, besides it being IDisposable.

It won't work:

```
using(var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel())
{
    return channel.ServiceMethod(parameter);
}
```

Instead you should:

```
public static class Service<T>
{
    public static ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>("");

    public static TResult Use<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        TResult output;
        var channel = (IClientChannel)_channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            output = func((T)proxy);
            channel.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}

return Service<IService>.Use(channel =>
{
    return channel.ServiceMethod(parameter);
});
```

Comment: I guess there is a mistake here: `channel` and `proxy` is the same thing. I think you should replace `proxy` with `channel`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to wrap your exceptions on the server side into FaultException. If you control both ends of the wire, and both ends are .NET, you can just simply wrap a .NET exception into a `FaultException<T>` and send that back to the client. That way the channel stays usable.

See [Specifying and Handling Faults in Contracts and Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx) on MSDN for more info, plus check out this [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFErrorHandling.aspx) and this blog post [Why Use WCF FaultException](https://web.archive.org/web/20090228085140/http://dotnet.org.za/willy/archive/2006/12/19/WCF-FaultException-_2620_-why-use-it_3F00_.aspx)  on the same topic.

Also, to make your life easier, check out the [IErrorHandler interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) which you can implement on the server side to globally catch exceptions and convert them into faults. Also see lots of blog posts on the topic, i.e. [IErrorHandler: a generic Fault Converter](http://blogs.u2u.be/nick/post/2009/10/11/IErrorHandler-A-generic-Fault-Converter-%2812%29.aspx) or many other (Bing or Google for more).

To make your life **even easier**, you can implement the IErrorHandler as a behavior, which you can turn on or off on your service - either in service config, or by setting an attribute on your service class. There's quite a few implementation floating around the internet, one I like is here: [Useful WCF Behavior: IErrorHandler](http://www.steverb.com/post/2008/11/24/Useful-WCF-Behaviors-IErrorHandler.aspx).

Comment: also found another solution, please see my answer

Comment: Interestingly my services stopped working when I implemented my solution, so I had to implement yours to get them back to normal.

Comment: I found the problem with my solution, we shouldn't dispose Channels, because they are tricky, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008382/how-to-heal-faulted-wcf-channels